# Virtual hosting ASP .NET websites in Windows IIS server with same port and same ip address

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, iis

I need to host multiple ASP .NET web sites on my windows IIS server. I have an ec2 insatnce of AWS. Can I host multiplse sites on that ec2 instance ? I have followed this link

http://techcerberus.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-host-multiple-website-on-amazon.html

This link helped me but I am only able to host multiple sites when ports are different

Also I have found different links which tells me to configure DNS and add bindings

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7HsUfry5Ks .

What is the best way to do it? I think giving different port to each website is not a good practise and cause a serious problem later.. But I am totally confuse how to do virtual hosting in an appropriate manner. Also can I use my ec2 instance to host multiple sites on same instance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can host multiple websites using multiple domains on a single IP address and port. This is known as Virtual Hosting.

Virtual Hosting on IIS/Apache Web Server will use the host header section in the HTTP request to determine which site configuration to us. The IIS/Apache Web Server will look at the HTTP Host header and make a decision on which Virtual Hosting configuration to use when servicing the request. In IIS you configure bindings for each site/domain that you are hosting.

- Host header information - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host
- IIS Virtual Hosting Information - https://simpledns.plus/kb/144/virtual-hosting-with-iis-internet-information-services
- If you are using SSL Certs - https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO20113.html

Answer (score 0):

This blog post may help. It gives three examples, but you are interested in example#2:

> Example 2:  Web server with one IP address using host name bindings
>   This situation is common at web hosting companies or in a
>   situation where you run a server from your house or small business and
>   only have one IP address to allocate to your web server.   Since we do
>   not have enough IP addresses to assign to each site, we will use host
>   headers to differentiate which website will serve requests.  In this
>   case, the only IP address on the server is 192.168.1.200.

https://www.sherweb.com/blog/cloud-server/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/